# CSS selector to find the last row in a table, which (row) does'n have specified class (CSS only, no javascript)

Tags: css, css-selectors

Please help me with CSS selector.

I need to apply special attributes to the last row in a table, which (row) **does'n have** specified class, for example class "zzz".

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd">...</tr>
        <tr class="even zzz">...</tr>
        <tr class="odd">...</tr>
        <tr class="even">This one should be selected</tr>
        <tr class="odd zzz">...</tr>
        <tr class="even zzz">...</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm looking for only pure CSS solution, not javascript one. Please don't suggest :not() pseudo-class, as some browsers do not support it.

Thank you for your help,

--Vadim

Comment: Do you absolutely need to support those browsers that do not support `:not()`? Could you please clarify exactly which browsers you need to support?

Comment: I need to support IE8+, FF, Chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, this is not doable with pure CSS, not even with a selector that only modern browsers support.

Comment: I suspected that, but I'm not CSS expert, so desided to ask help from community.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% certain i fully understand, but you can use something like

```
tr:last-child
```

in your css

Comment: Not a pure css solution, but [this script](https://gist.github.com/nathansmith/950767) allows you (or other users who find this) to use `last-child´ in IE7 & IE8